# NUnit test execution fails in jenkins but works via Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jenkins, nunit

Trying to hook up the CI process in jenkins for a .net (CS) project. The test executes fine from visual studio 2013

```
------ Run test started ------
NUnit Adapter 3.4.0.0: Test execution started
Running all tests in C:\Temp\project\test\IntegrationTests\bin\path_to_dll
NUnit3TestExecutor converted 14 of 14 NUnit test cases
Running all tests in C:\Temp\project\test\APIUnitTest\bin\path_to_dll
NUnit3TestExecutor converted 77 of 77 NUnit test cases
NUnit Adapter 3.4.0.0: Test execution complete
========== Run test finished: 91 run (0:00:30.777881) ==========
```

But executing the unit test (haven't tested executing the int test, yet) via command line from jenkins fails. Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385037/microsoft-fakes-wont-run-in-normal-unit-test-contexts) says, ms fakes will not work with nunit, how is the vs running the
nunit test?

Below is the error from the console for a test

```
18) Error : Some_Controller_name
[unitTestLab] Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException : Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and COR_PROFILER environment variables.
[unitTest]    at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.ResolveProfilerPath()
[unitTest]    at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.Initialize()
[unitTest]    at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.CreateContext()
```

My command line syntax for the nunit test execution is

```
D:\NUnit-3.2.1\bin\nunit3-console.exe ".\Path_to_dll" "--result:.\TestResult.xml
```

Comment: Got this open issue/feature request (https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/632 ) in nunit which proves that the Nunit is not to test related to Fakes. But still wondering why the visual studio was able to perform the same test using the nunit adapter?